# Re-center bootstrap modal vertically after content has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have successfully centered a bootstrap modal using the solution found here:

Demo: http://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc
Code: http://codepen.io/dimbslmh/pen/mKfCc

```
var contentHeight = $(window).height() - 60;
var headerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 2;
var footerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 2;
```

However, it doesn't work well with remotely loaded content. It's calculating the heights before the content is loaded. Then, after the content is loaded, the position is way off.

I've tried various methods to delay the calculations by a set time, but these methods have resulted in the modal loading at the top of the page, and then jumping down to the center.

It seems like the nicest solution would be to have it RE-CALCULATE the heights after the content is loaded. That way, the smaller modal (without the content) will load in the center, and then it will re-center once the content is loaded.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to use what you have but in the 'success' callback from the AJAX request.

Comment: Content is loaded in the modal by simply adding an href to the modal link. (Example: <a href="mycontent.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">) Do I need to open it programmatically in order to use the success callback?

Comment: I tried putting what I have into "$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {" but that broke the centering.

Comment: You need `loaded.bs.modal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) there is a method called `loaded.bs.modal` where the event '...is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.'

So with your code it would be something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function () {
  var contentHeight = $(window).height() - 60;
  var headerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 2;
  var footerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 2;
});
```

Here's a fork of that PEN that should work (haven't tested with remote source) http://codepen.io/craigmdennis/pen/fChIm

**Update based on comments.**

Its showing the modal before it calculates the width & height, then centers it once it's got them. You can't get dimensions from a hidden object as they don't have any until they're displayed. You'll have to add a class to the modal markup so you can set `visibility: hidden;` and `z-index: -99;` (so it's invisible and behind any content so not clickable) then remove the class when the `loaded.bs.modal` event is fired.

In the CSS:

```
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute; /* It will already have a position declaration */
  z-index: -99;
}
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function () {
  var contentHeight = $(window).height() - 60;
  var headerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-header').outerHeight() || 2;
  var footerHeight = $(this).find('.modal-footer').outerHeight() || 2;

  $(this).removeClass('invisible');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Craig! I don't know how I missed the loaded event! I tried this and was able to get it to work by wrapping the entire adjustsize function with the loaded.bs.modal function. However, it still does the same thing -- the modal loads first at the top of the browser, and then moves down to the center. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to load in the center both times. I tried repeating the function, once on "show.bs.modal" and again on "loaded.bs.modal" but it still does the same thing.

Comment: Its showing the modal before it calculates the height, then centers it once it's got the height.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I needed to move the "loaded.bs.modal' to surround the whole function, but otherwise, this did the trick. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: When clicking on any of the modal buttons on the codepen http://codepen.io/craigmdennis/pen/fChIm the modal does now show but only the .modal-backdrop and .fade in classes darken the preview. Was your codepen working when you first published it? Tested on latest version of Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps you can check yourself and let me know if it does work on your end? Thank you.

Comment: By the way this helped me answer a question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707548/bootstrap-3-3-2-how-to-get-modal-classes-height-on-shown-bs-modal-event though I am not using the invisible class and the event shown.bs.modal. So thank you for pointing me in the right direction. If you have a clue why my first approach did not work out let me know in an answer or comment on my question please. Would be great to understand the logic behind it completely. Thank you.