# Bootstrap 3.3.2 How to get modal classes height on shown.bs.modal event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the height of the Bootstrap 3.3.2 modal classes on the shown.bs.modal event. There is **no** remote content I am trying to load.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

The classes I like to have the height for are .modal-dialog, .modal-header, .modal-body and .modal-footer.

I am using this bit of jQuery but it gives me a value of either -31 or 0 for the height of the e.g. .modal-dialog and that is obviously wrong.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

    var modalDialogHeight = $('.modal-dialog').height();
    console.log ('modalDialogHeight = ' + modalDialogHeight);

});
```

I have created an example with Bootply here: [BS 3.3.2 How to get modal classes height on shown.bs.modal?](http://www.bootply.com/wZLYpnAvF1) and used console.log in the example.

However in the example nothing shows in the console though when running the default BS 3.3.2 modal locally without **any** customisations the log shows the wrong values or 0 in fact.

Tried using alert in the example but that also does not show. If anyone has a clue how to get this to work in Bootply let me know in a comment please.

Apart from that I am puzzled about the shown.bs.modal and .height() not working on the modal classes. It does fully work when adding

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
console.log ('viewportHeight = ' + viewportHeight);
```

to the local example, giving me the correct height. So the event does fire, however not on the modal classes.

How can I find out the height of the modal classes or why is my approach not working?

The reason I am trying to find the height of those classes is so that I can style the height of the entire modal and its content depending on the viewport height.

There is a similar question here [How to get Bootstrap modal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198035/how-to-get-bootstrap-modal-size) however I am calling after the event, just as lined out in the #modal-events given on the BS site and still no luck, and this as well with various widths of the viewport, narrow or wide.

Any help with this is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Research: [Re-center bootstrap modal vertically after content has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454132/1010918)

jQuery:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        console.log ('viewportHeight = ' + viewportHeight);

        var modalDialogHeight = $(this).find('.modal-dialog').outerHeight();
        console.log ('modalDialogHeight = ' + modalDialogHeight);

        var modalHeaderHeight = $(this).find('.modal-header').outerHeight();
        console.log ('modalHeaderHeight = ' + modalHeaderHeight);

        var modalBodyHeight = $(this).find('.modal-body').outerHeight();
        console.log ('modalBodyHeight = ' + modalBodyHeight);

        var modalFooterHeight = $(this).find('.modal-footer').outerHeight();
        console.log ('modalFooterHeight = ' + modalFooterHeight);       
    });
```

Explanation:
Bootstrap 3.3.2 apparently shows the modal before calculating its width and **height**.

Since the modal is hidden until it is being clicked it is impossible to get the width or **height** of the modal classes in question.

Once the event shown.bs.modal has fired it is possible to get the width and **height** of the modal classes and looking at my log it seems to work.

However **why**
`$(this).find('.modal-dialog').outerHeight();` works and  `$('.modal-dialog').height();` does not work might be due to the different jQuery methods used here, .height() and .outerHeight(). Though I must say that I did try using `.outerHeight` as well and it did not work, so it could be due to `$(this).find`.

*Attention:*
I am not entirely sure where my mistake was and if anyone can point out **exactly** why my first approach did not work I would be highly thankful, since then I can understand and learn this better. So thank you for any helping comments or different answers.

Reference: [jQuery .outerHeight()](https://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

> The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.
>
> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for
>   these, use .height() instead.

*Edit:*
After some reading and more coding I have come to understand that when trying to obtain either the width or the height of any of the modal classes, like `.modal-content` or `.modal-header`, for example, one does not really need the `shown.bs.modal` event.

In the following code the `.modal-content` width and height are calculated correctly when resizing the window when the modal is present.

This is accomplished by telling jQuery in what parent element to actually **find** the element whose width or height is wanted.

If the `.find()` method is **not** used it seems that jQuery cannot really get to the element in question and thus the calculations either are wrong values or result in 0.

Of course the code below can be used with the `shown.bs.modal` event to not have to resize the browser window for the log to start giving values. It is simply for my needs locally that I wrapped this in a window resize function with a callback.

Reference: [jQuery .find() method](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var modalContentWidthHeight = function () {

    var modalContentWidth = $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').outerWidth(true);
        console.log ('modalContentWidth = ' + modalContentWidth);

    var modalContentHeight = $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').outerHeight(true);
        console.log ('modalContentHeight = ' + modalContentHeight);     
    };

$(window).resize(modalContentWidthHeight);
```